# Why does a Dart Future affect a Flutter unit test?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing

If I add to a [simple unit test](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction)
the loading of an asset file in the constructor

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}

class Counter {
  int value = 0;
  void increment() => value++;
  void decrement() => value--;

  Counter() {
    loadAsset('assets/hello.txt').then((dynamic output) {
      print('$output');
    });
  }
}
```

without modifying the `Counter` class

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:counter/counter.dart';

void main() {
  test('Counter value should be incremented', () {
    final counter = Counter();

    counter.increment();

    expect(counter.value, 1);
  });
}
```

then I'm expecting that the test will continue to pass just the same.

I do not know whether

1. the `print` statement will execute before or after `counter.increment()`,
2. nor whether it will run before or after `expect(counter.value, 1)`,

but that doesn't matter, because the counter *will* be initialized before the first line of the constructor runs, and the `expect` can only run after `increment()` would have completed.

That's not the case. I get:

```
> flutter test test/counter_test.dart
Running "flutter pub get" in counter...                         1,010ms
00:03 +0 -1: Counter value should be incremented [E]
  Null check operator used on a null value
  package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 225:39  PlatformAssetBundle.load
  ...
  test/counter_test.dart 7:21                            main.<fn>
  
00:03 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Why does a Dart `Future` interfere with a Flutter test?

**Update**

OK, now that I've typed the question, I see the problem. The instance `final Counter` is not actually yet initialized when the increment and the expect statements run. That's by design, since the result of `await` could matter for the object.

Still, is there an inherent flaw in `await`-ing in a constructor (that's used in a test)? How would you rewrite this test if you want to initialize some data from an asset?

**Update 2**

This appears to be version-relevant. I'm using `Flutter 2.1.0-12.2.pre • channel beta`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the Future and not the loading of assets that fails?

Comment: @nvoigt You're right... but now I'm even more confused. Do you see what's happening? The code above is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your unit test to be executed first:

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Otherwise, you will have problems accessing the root bundle.